# windows 7 processor interrogation

Tags: c, windows, winapi, x86, windows-7

I have a PC with 24 cores.  I have an application that needs to dedicate a thread to one of those cores, and the process itself to a few of those cores.  The affinity and priorities are now hard-coded, I would like to programmatically determine what set of cores my application should set its affinity to.

I have read to stay away from core 0, I am currently using the last 8 cores on the first CPU for the process and the 12th core for the thread I want to run.  Here is sample code which may not be 100% accurate with the parameters.

```
SetProirityClass(getCurrentProcess(),REAL_TIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
SetProcessAffinityMask(getCurrentProcess(),0xFF0);
CreatThread(myThread, 0, entryPoint, NUll, 0, 0);//all 0 params besides handle and entry
SetThreadPriorityClass(myThread, TIME_CRITICAL);
SetThreadAffinityMask(myThread, 0x1 << 11);
```

I know that with elevated priorities (even with base priority 31) there is no way to dedicate a core to an application (Please correct me if I am wrong here since this is exactly what I want to do, non-programmatical solutions would be fine if I could do that).  That being said, the OS itself runs "mostly" on a core or a couple of cores.  Is it randomly determined on boot?  Can I interrogate available cores to programmatically determine which set of cores my process and `TIME_CRITICAL` thread should be running on?

Is there any way to prevent the kernel threads from stealing time slices of my `TIME_CRITICAL` thread?

I understand windows is not real time but I'm doing the best with what I have.  The solution needs to apply to win 7 but if it is also supported under XP that would be great.

Comment: It all sounds rather pointless. Why bother with affinities and priorities at all. I mean, you aren't running any other processes on this machine I presume.

Comment: On this PC its main purpose is run this single program, but there are other programs that also can run (text editor/log stuff/other stuff).  Even if it were the only user process its not *really* the only process because windows kernal threads are running, occasionally stealing time slices from my TIME_CRITICAL thread.

Comment: I once tried to write a time-critical application on Windows. After awhile I gave up and moved to Linux. However, I didn't know about processor affinity at the time. I think using processor affinity is the correct approach if you have to stick with Windows (I'd still set the process priority high).

Comment: The kernel "things" that can steal time from a processors are: APC, DPC, Kernel Threads, ISR. With [IRQ Affinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/interrupt-affinity-and-priority) you should tick off ISR and DPC (most of it). Kernel APC should be rare if you don't do overlapped IO and no other threads are scheduled on that core. Kernel threads are not under the user control but are infrequent. In general, if you don't schedule other thread on a core and off-load the IRQs from it you should receive very little OS jittering.

Comment: It is said that Windows 8+ is also dynamic ticking/tickless like Linux. I would give IRQ affinity a try and see how much noise remains. BTW, you can query the number of cores but maybe it's easier to let it a config parameter.

Comment: On Linux some systems assign the logical threads of a physical core in 1a 1b 2a 2b order, while for others it's 1a 2a 1b 2b.  If Windows is the same, you'll need to be careful to not pin multiple threads to logical cores of the same physical CPU, if that's not what you want.

Comment: If you do run other processes then you can't be sure this will work out. Those process could affinities to the same processors that you choose. Reducing the number of processors that can be used to run your process doesn't sound like a way to make it more likely to be run. It sounds like you'll make it less likely to run. Perhaps you should consider a real time OS.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thanks Margaret, this TIME_CRITICAL thread is actually for an ISR that waits for an IRQ generated from a PCI card.  I am trying to do something real time on windows, which i know is hopeless but  atleast i can try to make it perform as best as possible.  I'll set the relevant IRQ to the core im reserving, and to a separate core, and profile both.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I wish i could use a real time OS but that decision it out of my hands.  As a back up plan, I plan on using a small PIC to do essentially what this attempt at a windows ISR is doing, at a later date when the small amount of timing misses i currently get really count.

Comment: And you know all this and you still intend to run other user processes?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was under the impression that if i have a deadlocked thread with base priority 31 it would hog the core, prevent all other user processes from being allocated time slices on that core.  Is that not the case?  I appreciate your insight into this.  These PCs are used by other teams that run other things for data collection on certain external HW, like 1553 bus monitoring programs for example.  I can not prevent them from doing that.

Comment: Kinda pointless to attempt real time if you let other processes have their way. Surely you can see that? A deadlocked thread doesn't consume CPU, it is not scheduled at all to run because it is waiting for a sync object. Threads can't run when they are waiting.

Comment: I understand that other processes should not "have their way", thats why I'm trying to reserve a core with these windows API functions.  I was lead to believe that manipulating the base priority would reserve the core for my thread.  It basically just waits for an IRQ from the PCI card, then calls the ISR, in a while loop.  The function to wait for the IRQ was provided by the company that makes the PCI card.

The attempt at real time was to reduce the number of timing errors for a signal going out to external HW.  If, for example, I have 3 misses in 24 hours i consider that pretty good.

Comment: No, that's not how it works. Just because you say that a thread can only run on a specific processor does not in any way prevent another thread being scheduled to run there also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181723/discussion-between-bwebb-and-david-heffernan). NM i cant use chat apparently.  I understand that setting the affinity itself is not an improvement, but if the base priority of the thread is higher than any other thread/process on that core that i thought it would "starve" other threads/processes, effectively blocking out user threads.  If i am way off base can you please link me some relevant info?  I am new to windows API.  I appreciate your help David.

Comment: I mean, if you want to do this, then clearly no amount of reasoning is going to stop you. You've already decided to do this. Difficult to know what more to say.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well thank you for your contributions to my question.  I did not mean to come off negatively towards you if thats how you read my responses.  I dont have much experience with windows API and i still dont see a reason why my attempt is not valid at preventing user-threads from using the dedicated core im trying to reserve.  I know there are things i cant prevent from running on it but with these windows API functions i figured it would atleast block user level stuff.  This is not for an application that will be distributed to external customers, if that clarifies my situation.